# Why does directx9 AddDirtyRect cause memory violation on Intel integrated graphics?

Tags: graphics, directx, driver, direct3d, directx-9

I'm using the following code to lock an IDirect3DTexture9 for update. This piece of code works fine on my NVidia graphic card (NVidia GeForce GTX 970M) but causes memory violation on Intel integrated graphic card (Intel HD Graphics 530), even the texture is immediately unlocked and no data is written on locked region. x, y, w and h parameters are far from boundary conditions so the locked rect is totally inside the texture.

```
void InnerLock(int x, int y, int w, int h, D3DLOCKED_RECT *lr)
{
    int left, right, top, bottom;
    left = clamp(x, 0, Width() - 1);
    top = clamp(y, 0, Height() - 1);
    right = clamp(x + w, left + 1, Width());
    bottom = clamp(y + h, top + 1, Height());
    RECT rc = { left, top, right, bottom };

    texture->LockRect(0, lr, &rc, D3DLOCK_NO_DIRTY_UPDATE);
    // this line returns zero but causes an exception on igdumdim32.dll later
    texture->AddDirtyRect(&rc)

    // everything become all right when I set the whole texture as dirty region
    //RECT fc = { 0, 0, Width(), Height() };
    //texture->AddDirtyRect(&fc);
}
```

The AddDirtyRect operator returns correct value, but the error occurs later in igdumdim32.dll (I'm not sure where the error exactly occurs, maybe in the draw call).

I first found the error when using LockRect with zero flag. The program crashed on some rect parameter (in my case the error occurred when y value of the rect is large enough, but still smaller than texture height). Then I used D3DLOCK_NO_DIRTY_UPDATE and manually added dirty rect. The error only occurs when AddDirtyRect is called.

This error is reproduced on another user with intel graphics card. My operating system is Windows 10. All drivers are updated to the latest version. If you need any information please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: Direct3D 9 development on Windows 8.x or Windows 10 is quite challenging. It's a legacy API that is intended for appcompat, not development which today should be using Direct3D 11 or Direct3D 12. The last version of Windows to support the Direct3D 9 debug device (a.k.a. the Direct3D Developer Runtime) was Windows 7. It is possible there is a driver bug here because dirty rectangle usage like this was quite rare.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thanks for your reply. I have already found that Direct3D debug device doesn't work on Windows 10. But my program is an implementation of a legacy game framework and it is intended to support some old systems. I would like to know if any methods and tools can help debug and fix this kind of problems.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'some old system'? How old?  Really to do Direct3D 9 debugging you need a Windows 7 system or vm.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn It's Windows 2000 or XP. I am going to install a VM for debugging. Thank you.

Comment: You really need to develop and test stuff on the minimum supported hardware and OS platform as well as new ones (regardless of lack of support in newer systems, using newer hardware makes it easy to accidentally depend on features that did not previously exist). But do you really need 2000, XP, or Vista? Not many people use those and the share is only going down. Using the modern D3D11 API for 7+ would give you an easier time even if performance is not important.